# c# TimeOut all httpwebrequests

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest

this is not a question on how to abort thread pointhunters.

i am making a `multi-threaded` program which has a `httpwebrequest` in each one of the running threads and I figured that if I want to stop all of them what they are doing midway thru I must time them out.
is there a way to do that on a multi-threaded basis?
each thread looks like this:

```
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/html";
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        webRequest.Timeout = 1000 * 10;
        webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 100;
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36";
        webRequest.Proxy = null;
        WebResponse resp;
        string htmlCode = null;

        try
        {
           resp = webRequest.GetResponse();
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
           htmlCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
           sr.Close();
           resp.Close();
         }
    catch (Exception)
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: what is not formated about it?

Comment: Is this how your code looks in your IDE?

Comment: yes, im a messy person ill try to prettify it for you. do you know how to do the timeout thing i am trying to achieve? i cant just abort the threads.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a safe way to stop a running thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272332/what-is-a-safe-way-to-stop-a-running-thread)

Answer (score 0):

Timing out events explicitly is not a good method. You may want to look into
[Cancel Async Tasks after a Period of Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/jj155760.aspx).

> You can cancel an asynchronous operation after a period of time by
>   using the CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter method if you don't want
>   to wait for the operation to finish. This method schedules the
>   cancellation of any associated tasks that aren’t complete within the
>   period of time that’s designated by the CancelAfter expression.

Sample code from MSDN :

```
// Declare a System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.
        CancellationTokenSource cts;

        private async void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Instantiate the CancellationTokenSource.
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();    
            resultsTextBox.Clear();    
            try
            {
                // ***Set up the CancellationTokenSource to cancel after 2.5 seconds. (You 
                // can adjust the time.)
                cts.CancelAfter(2500);    
                await AccessTheWebAsync(cts.Token);
                resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads succeeded.\r\n";
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads canceled.\r\n";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads failed.\r\n";
            }    
            cts = null; 
        }    

        // You can still include a Cancel button if you want to. 
        private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cts != null)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
            }
        }    

        async Task AccessTheWebAsync(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            // Declare an HttpClient object.
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();    
            // Make a list of web addresses.
            List<string> urlList = SetUpURLList();    
            foreach (var url in urlList)
            {
                // GetAsync returns a Task<HttpResponseMessage>.  
                // Argument ct carries the message if the Cancel button is chosen.  
                // Note that the Cancel button cancels all remaining downloads.
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, ct);    
                // Retrieve the website contents from the HttpResponseMessage. 
                byte[] urlContents = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();    
                resultsTextBox.Text +=
                    String.Format("\r\nLength of the downloaded string: {0}.\r\n"
                   , urlContents.Length);
            }
        }
```

There is also [Thread.Abort Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which terminates the thread.

***EDIT :*** **Canceling the Task** - *A better Explanation ([source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/996857/Asynchronous-programming-and-Threading-in-Csharp-N))*

The Task class provides a way to cancel the started task based on the CancellationTokenSource class.

Steps to cancel a task:

1. The asynchronous method should except a parameter of type `CancellationToken`
2. Create an instance of CancellationTokenSource class like: `var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();`
3. Pass the CancellationToken from the instace to the asynchronous method, like: `Task<string> t1 = GreetingAsync("Bulbul", cts.Token);`
4. From the long running method, we have to call ThrowIfCancellationRequested() method of CancellationToken.

   ```
             static string Greeting(string name, CancellationToken token)
               {
                  Thread.Sleep(3000);
                  token. ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                 return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
               }
   ```
5. Catch the `OperationCanceledException` from where we are awiting for the Task.
6. We can cancel the operation by calling `Cancel` method of instance of `CancellationTokenSource`, `OperationCanceledException` will be thrown from the long running operation. We can set time to cancel the operation to the instanc also.

Further Details - [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CallWithAsync();
        Console.ReadKey();           
    }

    async static void CallWithAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            source.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            var t1 = await GreetingAsync("Bulbul", source.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static Task<string> GreetingAsync(string name, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.Run<string>(() =>
        {
            return Greeting(name, token);
        });
    }

    static string Greeting(string name, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
    }
```

Comment: but i can simply set a timeout to my httpwebrequest. is there a way i can access the object im creating? i have a threadlist of all the threads.

Comment: You are trying to `Timeout` the `HttpWebRequest` which is being executed on your thread. I dont think that would be possible or even if it is. That is not the right way.

Comment: @tim_po - Please see the Edit, I have added explanation of usage of `CancellationToken`